# what is this addSelectionInterval(int index0,int index1) for?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

I'm studying JTree now, and this early I've encountered a problem. 
what is 'addSelectionInterval' method and when do you use it?
it says - Adds the paths between index0 and index1, inclusive, to the selection.
and what is this index? Does it mean node0 to node1?

Comment: Did you check the javadocs/try it?

Comment: and see constants for TreeSelectionModel.XXX_XXX

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel/addSelectionInterval(int%20index0,int%20index1).html

Look at the official java docs. They can help

Also if you want something more **specific**:

```
import javax.swing.JList;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    JList list = new JList(items);

    int start = 2;
    int end = 2;
    list.addSelectionInterval(start, end); 
  }
}
```

This example uses JList but the index you are looking for is in theory (start, end)

Comment: The question is about a JTree.

Comment: I thought he was asking about the the indexes and what types of values they stored

Comment: thank you BDillan. I finally got it. I had some kind of trouble finding information about it cause I'm not really good at english especially in programming term. But this totally helped me understand what is the method for, and index is what's in array

Comment: @user2651974, `I had some kind of trouble finding information about it` - all you have to do is search the forum using `addSelectionInterval` and you will find plenty of examples. If you include `tree` as a search word you will probably even find tree examples.

Comment: Thank you camickr for your attention to this matter. This will greatly help me